# Swift: Get indexes of smallest items in 2-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

In Swift, is there a built-in method to get the indexes of the smallest items in a 2-dimensional array? Something like this pseudo code:

```
let array = [[1,4,8,3,9],[2,6,5,13,19]]

for item in 0...4 {
     2dimensionalIndex = array.smallest(item)  
}
```

Which then gives me the indices `[0][0],[1][0],[0][3],[0][1],[1][2]`?

**Edit:**

Background: I have a 2-dimensional array of CircularRegions and a user location. Since I can only register 20 regions for Geofencing, I compute the distance between the center of each region and the user location minus the radius of the region. Now I have a 2-dimensional array of distances. I want the indexes of the 20 smallest distances to register the regions.

Comment: Yeah, downvote. I'm new to this, I searched a lot, I don't want to reinvent the wheel, which I did a lot...

Comment: Is the result you are looking for `[0][0],[1][0],[0][3],[0][1],[1][2]?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "built-in" method. Here is a possible approach:

```
let array = [[1,4,8,3,9],[2,6,5,13,19]]

let sorted2DIndices = array.enumerate().flatMap {
        (i, row) in row.enumerate().map {
            (j, elem) in (i, j, elem)
        }
    }
    .sort { $0.2 < $1.2 }
    .map { (i, j, elem) in (i, j) }

print(sorted2DIndices)
// [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 3), (0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1), (0, 2), (0, 4), (1, 3), (1, 4)]
```

The outer `enumerate()` enumerates the rows and the inner
`enumerate()` the columns of the 2D array. Together with `flatMap()`
and `map()`, this gives an array of `(i, j, elem)` triples where 
`i` is the row index and `j` the column index of `elem`.

This array is sorted according to the elements, and then
mapped to an array of 2D indices.

`sorted2DIndices[0]` is the 2D index of the smallest element, etc.
You can also get the indices of the four smallest elements with

```
let first4 = sorted2DIndices.prefix(4)
print(first4)
// [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 3), (0, 1)]
```

Comment: Having trouble to understand it, but it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's what you're looking for:

```
let array = [[1,4,8,3,9],[2,6,5,13,19]]
array.map { $0.indexOf($0.minElement()!)! }
```

Comment: Result: `[Optional(0), Optional(0)]`. That isn't what the OP asked for. I don't understand what the OP wants but this certainly isn't it.

Comment: Which is the index of the smallest item, sounds cool. Unfortunately I don't understand the syntax, how to get the 2nd smallest?